# Domain and Search View in action window odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view, odoo-12

I have created new action window in odoo12:

```
   <record id="action_sales_line" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Searching</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="domain">[('order_id', '=', ???)]</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>
```

which display all records of sale order line as a wizard in sale module. What I want to do here is to have search view in that wizard and also domain must filter the result of a selected specific order i.e SO001, SO002 and have to be dynamic. So How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filter selected sale order id you have to pass active_id in the domain. Like the following:

```
<record id="action_sales_line" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Searching</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="domain">[('order_id', '=', active_id)]</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you It works as I was expected .... But How to find all field that domain accepts ? ... Any one know how to show search view ?